# extract a particular subset having a specific date

Tags: pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe named df which contains a column named 'Last Updated', so now i want to make a subset named updated_data where i have condition on subset  "observations which was Last Updated on 2020-06-13 03:33:14".Help me out to do this. just want to make the subset from this specified time.

i tried this,

```
updated_data=df[df['Last Updated']== 6/13/2020 03:33:14
```

but this shows error as

> File "", line 1
> updated_data=df[df['Last Updated']== 6/13/2020 3:33]
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `updated_data=df[df['Last Updated']== '6/13/2020 03:33:14']`

Comment: Provide sample data to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
updated_data=df[df['Last Updated']== '6/13/2020 03:33:14']
```

if it shows you error then try to add the date and time in qoutes